# Why NextJS changes ID or class of some elements?

Tags: html, next.js

I have a problem where ID or class name of an element changes after rendering page, when I create element like this

```
function Overlay() {
    return <div id={style.overlay}><Region id={style.overlay_svg} className="overlay_svg" /></div>
}
```

and then when I inspect in browser it looks like this

```
<div id="overlay_overlay___U_wp">
    <svg id="overlay_overlay_svg__dHS6_" class="overlay_svg"></svg>
</div>
```

But when I create it like this

```
function HomePage() {
return <>
    <Head>
    <title>Wineata - Atlas</title>
    <meta property="og:title" content="Wineata - Atlas" key="title" />
    </Head>
    <WineataNavbar/>
    <Container fluid className="background flex-grow-1">
        <Row><Col id='wineata'>
            <WineAtlas id='atlas' /><Overlay />
        </Col></Row>
    </Container>
</>
}
```

all elements get IDs I assigned them. This later makes me trouble when I want to access elements using jQuery

Comment: In the first scenario you're using [CSS modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules) so that's expected behaviour - CSS modules hashes the class names to locally scope them. Why are you using CSS modules/class names to name `id` attributes?

Comment: You're using Next.js, which is a React framework - you should avoid accessing elements by class names or using jQuery altogether. React provides `ref`s for that purpose, see https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html.

Comment: Oh okay, I get it now whats happening. I am new to this so obviously I don't know what I'm doing. What I am creating is interactive map that is SVG. I haven't managed to find any meaningful how to do using react/nextjs, so I just imported script that I used before switching to NextJS. Here is code sample of JS script [link](https://codeshare.io/ZJvvrz)